# Xcode 4 - exclude Three20 module from target build

Tags: xcode4, build, three20

I'd like to exclude

**libThree20UINavigator.a** from my build,

I did it in Xcode 3 by uncheck it from Target build

[image]

Do you know how to do it in Xcode 4?

There must be something like this but I couldn't find where it is for **Three20UINavigator**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the library from the project navigator should allow you to use the Target Membership checkboxes to exclude the library, as shown in your Xcode 4 screenshot. I know it works for frameworks. I don't have a static library to test on Xcode 4.

If selecting the library from the project navigator doesn't work, remove the library from the target's Link Binary with Libraries build phase. Select the project from the project navigator to open the project editor. Select the target from the left side of the project editor. Click the Build Phases button at the top of the project editor. Click the disclosure triangle in the Link Binary with Libraries build phase. Select the library from the list of linked libraries. Click the minus button to remove the library from the target.

Answer (score 1):

It's located in a different menu in xcode 4.

Click on the project name from the left nab bar, and then pick your release / debug target name from the Targets list in the right side.

All the framework and libraries that are included to that target will be under the "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary with Libraries". You should be able to remove the unnecessary libraries from that list.